# Android app to circuit trigger

Tags: wifi, open-hardware

I am planning to create a device which is connected to wifi and triggers a current when I send some signal to it using wifi.

This will be something like unlock an electronic door remotely. What all components will be needed to do something like this?

I will be using Android for triggering the signal. Any help will be appreciated. Any recommendation for any pre-built device will be useful too.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Your question shows no effort at research and so is very broad and likely to be closed. Please be aware that questions seeking product recommendations are not allowed either and that will definitely get your question closed. You need to edit and ask a specific question about a design you are considering.

Comment: i had done some RnD on it and it suggested using some blueberry circuit which i dint had any clue of :)

Comment: Did you mean "raspberry"? As I googled it, "blueberry circuit" is a band! Do you intend to use this circuit that you'll build in a "serious" application? Is this a critical situation? If the circuit fails, if the power shutts down, if the batteries run off, what will you do? For your sake, dont' use this device in a "serious" environment.

Comment: it will be integrated with webcam feed on android to check and open the door.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend you to use ESP8266 ,especially ESP-12E for such wifi based controlling. It costs only ~$5. All you need to do is ,learn the esp to program(preferably Arduino), Connect to wifi network broadcasted by the esp chip and you're done for connection part. The ESP-12E have lot of peripherals like GPIO ,from which you can switch relay( buy a 3.3v relay switch), I2C , SPI so on. For Android app, you don't necessary need it. You can control it with your webpage itself by programming the chip appropriately. If you want a android app, try to create an app by your own. There are lot of free tools available for creating android app, and it'll take less time to create such app. For unlocking door, you can use a servo motor. Nevertheless , try not to use the door unlocking your main door of home. Chances that a hackers may hack for the WiFi password and they access to your home. So try the door unlocking for your small rooms inside your home itself.

---

The most critical part you need is ESP-12E itself. For door unlocking/locking ,you need a servo motor which you need to connect to the door in such a way that ,when it rotates 90 degree, it unlocks and after 30 sec(say) it'll automatically lock and Arduino IDE with ESP library installed(get it from GitHub).For controlling, you need at least a web browser with wifi connection(it can be a laptop, phone) or android phone ,with app created by you (refer google for easy way to do apps) and add stuffs like power supply etc., by yourself

Comment: my door is connected to an electronic lock, which just need small current to open :)

Comment: As @aadarsh has said, "try not to use the door unlocking your main door of home." (...) "So try the door unlocking for your small rooms inside your home itself."

Comment: Then no problem, all you need is a relay(if it takes lot of current) or a driver IC(if it takes low current ~0.5A),controlled by the esp GPIO pin

Comment: that has to be soldered on the board or is it plug and play kind of thing?

Comment: It's like breadboard connectable module and also comes with USB->UART interface built in with it. Also note that there is also ESP-12E which they sell only chip. I WON'T RECOMMEND YOU TO BUY THAT, because you have overhead of soldering in a PCB. Buy a ESP-12E module with USB connector with it.

Comment: @Aadarsh - I am using private IP for unlock wont be making it public? Still it can be hacked?